# how to restart dafny in VS code when it gets frozen

Tags: visual-studio-code, dafny

Before I start moaning let me state I am very impressed with Dafny.

I have managed to get Dafny-VScode frozen on several occasions and would like to know if there is a better way to "reboot" Dafny with out just shutting down VS code.  The example below is a cut down version of what I am working on so it may seem a little pointless:

```
method sortOfImp(s:seq<int>) returns (r:seq<int>)
{
  var i:int:= 1;
  r:=[];
  if |s|>= 2 {
    while (i<|s|) 
      decreases |s| - i
      invariant i<=|s| 
     // invariant forall j:nat :: 0<j<i ==> ( s[j]<=s[j-1] ==> 
     //      (exists  ii:nat :: ii<|r| && r[ii]==s[j]) )  
     {  
       if s[|s|-i-1] <= s[|s|-i] {  r:= [s[|s|-i]]+r;}
       i:=i+1; 
     }    
  } 
}
```

loads and behaves nicely.  But if you uncomment the two lines an error is reported (no problem there) now restore the comments and the errors do not go away plus other errors are not reported.

The only solution I have found is to quit VS code and when restarted the errors are no longer reported and everything works as you would expect.

The other part of the question is:
*what part of the invariant does dafny object?*